# Regex locate number followed by space followed by character

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I tried to locate only number followed by space and a character after it.

```
Exemple : text = "3 R"
```

and want it to be like this :

```
Exemple : text = "3. R"
```

i've tried this code :

```
text= re.sub(r'([0-9])(?!.*\d)', r'\1. ', text)
```

Am getting closer but don't know what should i add to it.

**Update**

Text :

```
Évitez les conversations malsaines en utilisant les 3 R, à savoir 
‘reformuler, recentrer et réorienter’. Créez un cadre confortable en 
reformulant les phrases susceptibles de générer des émotions négatives. Vous 
pouvez également reformuler des reproches tels que : « Cela m’ennuie que tu 
passes autant de temps sur des projets de moindre importance qui ne mènent 
nulle part » en disant plutôt « J’aimerais que tu consacres les efforts que 
tu fournis dans ton travail à davantage de nouveaux projets plutôt qu’à 
quelques projets peu importants... Je suis sûr que tu disposes maintenant de 
suffisamment d’expérience pour gérer des projets inédits et ambitieux. »
```

my regex code :

```
    text= re.sub(r'\s*(?!\.[’"])([.,?:])(?!(?<=\d.)\d)\s*', r'\1 ', text)
    text= re.sub(r'\s*([-])\s*', r'\1', text)
    text= re.sub(u"\u2013", " ", text)
    text= re.sub(r'(\d)\s+(?=\d)', r'\1', text)
    text= re.sub(r'(\d)\/+(?=\d)', r'\1 ', text)
    text= re.sub(r'([0-9])\b(?!.*\d)',r'\1. ', text)
```

Output:

```
Évitez les conversations malsaines en utilisant les 3 R, à savoir 
‘reformuler, recentrer et réorienter’. Créez un cadre confortable en 
reformulant les phrases susceptibles de générer des émotions négatives. Vous 
pouvez également reformuler des 
reproches tels que:  Cela m’ennuie que tu passes autant de temps sur des 
projets de moindre importance qui ne mènent nulle part  en disant plutôt  
J’aimerais que tu consacres les efforts que tu fournis dans ton travail à 
davantage de nouveaux projets plutôt qu’à quelques projets peu importants, Je 
suis sûr que tu disposes maintenant de suffisamment d’expérience pour gérer 
des projets inédits et ambitieux.
```

i've tried the codes suggested by you guys but not working idk why, text is a long string.

The problem could be due to using too much regex??

I'm using python3.9

**snippet**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Define an input and your desired output for that, it's ambiguous.

Comment: Use a word boundary, `([0-9])\b(?!.*\d)`

Comment: You may use: `re.sub(r'(\d)(?= \D)', r'\1.', text)`

Comment: no i've tried your both answers and not working.

Comment: @MaskedMan i want 3 R to be turned to 3. R

Comment: @anubhava it doesn't turn 3 R to 3. R

Comment: `re.sub(r'(\d)( [a-zA-Z])', r'\1.\2', text)` should work too.

Comment: @Adgogo: `re.sub(r'(\d)(?= \D)', r'\1.', '3 R')` gives `3. R`

Comment: `re.sub(r'([0-9])\b(?!.*\d)', r'\1.', text)` [**works, too**](https://regex101.com/r/Z092id/1/). This is a problem is matching a digit not followed with a word char, basically, matching at a word boundary.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's working on regex website, but weirdly not working for me, idk why

Comment: Show the code that fails. Are you using raw string literals with both the regex and replacement? Please edit the question to see if there are other issues than just matching a whole number.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i've added my whole code

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew instead of doing what it should do, it turns this : en 1998, some text INTO en 1998. , some text

Comment: Based on your input and output I could come up with this: `re.sub(r"(\d+)(?:\s+)(.*)", r"\1. \2", text)`.

Comment: @MaskedMan it's working on a separated file but when i add it to my code it's not working, probably due to using much regex or idk what else could be

Comment: You can provide your code snippet to clarify.

Comment: @MaskedMan i've added a snippet of my code

Comment: In your snippet I'm not seeing my regex, maybe you forgot to include it.

Comment: @MaskedMan excuses, check again please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230903/discussion-between-masked-man-and-adgogo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the constraints you defined (input/output) and the discussion we had you can use this snippet:

```py
re.sub(r"(\d+)(?:\s+)(\w)", r"\1. \2", text)
```

Comment: thank you sooo much, can u please explain why the previous solution didn't work, bc in regex website it worked but not for me

Comment: @anubhava still the only solution that worked for me, i'm already using a regex code to ignore spaces inside a number.

Comment: @Adgogo: I have shown how the very first solution I gave is working fine. You can copy/paste my suggested in your code anywhere and test. Fact that you have many more `sub` calls is muddling the water

Comment: @anubhava u can check in the snippet that i've tried your code but it didn't work for me, instead it's working on a separated file idk why

Comment: No I don't see `r'(\d)(?= \D)'` anywhere in your question

Comment: @anubhava  please check line 29 on first snippet

Comment: That is not code snippet but a screenshot. Anyway I have already explained that `Fact that you have many more sub calls is muddling the water`. Comment out 5 `sub` calls before that and then test it.

Comment: Just FYI: `r"(\d+)(?:\s+)(\w)"`  = `r"(\d+)\s+(\w)"`. It is also equal to `re.sub(r"\d+(?=\s+\w)", r"\g<0>. ", text)`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
re.sub('(\d)\s([a-zA-Z])', r'\1. \2', text)
```

It replaces the `3 R` with `3. R`. Also works with bigger numbers, like `31789 R`, and lowercase `3 r`.